# Return to flat series from a pandas crosstab

Tags: python, pandas

I've have a time series in a pandas DataFrame (a list of IP connections with two IP addresses):

```
data=[["192.168.1.199","192.168.1.22"],["192.168.1.199","192.168.1.22"],["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2"], ["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2"],["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2"],["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.3"],["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.99"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
flows = pd.crosstab(df[0],df[1])
```

flows is

```
1              192.168.1.2  192.168.1.22  192.168.1.3  192.168.1.99
0                                                                  
192.168.1.1              3             0            1             1
192.168.1.199            0             2            0             0
```

But I'd like to get

```
        count         dstip         srcip
     0      3   192.168.1.2   192.168.1.1
     1      1   192.168.1.3   192.168.1.1
     2      1  192.168.1.99   192.168.1.1
     3      2  192.168.1.22  192.168.1.99
```

Thanks for your help. The goal is to feed that in a plotting library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
s = df.groupby([1, 0])[1].count()
flows = pd.DataFrame({'count': s.values, 'dstip': s.index.droplevel(0),
                      'srcip': s.index.droplevel(1)})

>> flows

   count         dstip          srcip
0      3   192.168.1.2    192.168.1.1
1      2  192.168.1.22  192.168.1.199
2      1   192.168.1.3    192.168.1.1
3      1  192.168.1.99    192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks you ! That perfect Mike

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you have the privilege to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). ;)

Comment: Oh yes. I am not so familiar with stack exchange 'etiquette' . done